# Probability in combinatorics

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Here is the problem. I have 3 marbles in a bag, a red one, a blue one and a green one. Let's say you win a prize if you pick the red marble and let's say that you can pick two times in the bag and each time you have to put the marble back in the bag. Here are then the possible results if you say that picking red then blue is the same as picking blue then red:

$$RR \space \space \space BB \space \space \space GG$$
$$RB \space \space \space RG$$
$$BG$$

So in this case their are 6 distinguishable results and in 3 of them, you win so you have $3/6=1/2=50\%$ chance of winning.

Now let's say that this time, you are interested in the number of results there are if picking a red then a blue is not the same as picking a blue then a red:

$$RR \space \space \space BB \space \space \space GG$$
$$RB \space \space \space BG \space \space \space GB$$
$$RG \space \space \space BR \space \space \space GR$$

So now there are 9 distinguishable results and in 5 of them, you win so the pobability that you win in this case goes to $5/9 \approx 0.56 =56\%$ chance of winning right?

My problem with this is obvious, the result should be $50\%$ what is the problem with the second case?

Comment: The first case makes no sense to me. According to the rules described in the problem you should always use $5\over 9$ and ignoring possible cases does not make sense.

Comment: oh ok I see. Thank you.

Comment: If the rules was "picking two balls at the same time and if any of them is red" then you are able to ignore order. However in that case $RR,GG,BB$ are not possible so you don't get $1\over2$ either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct answer is $5/9$.

Unless the problem contains direct definitions of probabilities of some events, the usual way is to find some set of 'elementary' ('atomic', 'simple') events for which you can say that sum of their probabilities is $1$ and they are symmetric so that their probabilities should be equal. In problem description, such symmetry usually is denoted by words 'fair', 'totally random' and the like. Here you get "totally random" marble from the bag each time, so probability of *not* getting red one is $2/3$. Probability of failing two times in a row (either since different attempts are 'independent' or since you get "totally random" **ordered** pairs of balls) is $4/9$ and probability of winning is $5/9$.

Comment: So the problem is that I am ignoring some results in the first case?

Comment: @Dibs For listed events (**unordered** pairs) your problem description doesn't let you to say that their probabilities are equal. One can say that you either assign probabilities without justification or ignore events $BR$, $GR$ and $GB$.

Comment: Oh ok then. Than you for your answer!